# Find length of a column in Sql loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to add a missing ending double quotes using sql loader code for a specific column. Looks like "LENGTH" is not a valid sql loader command.

Eg:
SR_ARTIST_TX                CHAR(4000) "CASE WHEN (substr(:SR_ARTIST_TX,1,1) = '"' and substr(:SR_ARTIST_TX,
length(:SR_ARTIST_TX)) ) != '"' THEN
:SR_ARTIST_TX||'"'
else
:SR_ARTIST_TX
END"  ,

Data:
3,A263163706496582,QMGXA1727673,A Different Time (Full),"Bruce Edward Chianese,Test;

Does anybody have any better idea?

Thanks in advance
Mohan

I am expecting double quotes must be added if it is missing one.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test SQL*Loader, but - if `SUBSTR` works, then use only that function. Lucky you, there's an easy way out:

```
SQL> select substr('abc', -1) from dual;

S
-
c

SQL>
```

Therefore:

```
SR_ARTIST_TX CHAR(4000) "CASE WHEN (substr(:SR_ARTIST_TX,1,1) = '"' and
                                    substr(:SR_ARTIST_TX, -1) != '"' THEN :SR_ARTIST_TX||'"' else :SR_ARTIST_TX END",
                                                         ---
                                                         This
```